# WordPress' checked() function echo's checked='checked'

Tags: php, html, wordpress, checkbox

I'm writing a WordPress plugin and have a checkbox in a form.

If the checkbox is checked it saves the value to the database and shows up checked in the form. However if the checkbox is checked it outputs `checked='checked'` in the form.

So the checkbox works like it needs to work but I cant see why it outputs `checked='checked'` to the form.

```
public function display() {
    
    $html = '';
    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'nonce_check_value' );
    $html .= '<label for="CMBUserBoxName">Name metabox: </label>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="CMBUserBoxName" value="' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'CMBUserBoxName', true ). '">';
    $html .= '<h1>What do you need?</h1>';
    $html .= '<label for="CMBUserCheckbox">Checkbox: </label>';
    $checkedByUser = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'CMBUserCheckbox', true );
    $html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="CMBUserCheckbox" value="1" '.checked( $checkedByUser, 1 ).' />';

    echo $html;
}
```

The output on screen is as followed
[image]

Comment: because wordpress is stupid, those sorta functions actually include an echo, so you're echoing the `checked` function return twice - can fix by just using `isset` or some other std php function :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`checked()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) function `echo`s by default. Use `false` in the last parameter to return the string instead of echo.

```
$html .= '<input type="checkbox" name="CMBUserCheckbox" value="1" '.checked( $checkedByUser, 1, false).' />';
```

Comment: Dude... perfect

Answer (score 0):

Using wordpress Checked() function you can do this

```
<input checked class="classname" value="checkvalue" id="" type="radio" name="" <?php echo checked( get_option('get_check_box_value'), 'checkvalue') ?>>
```

Comment: That code looks completely different to the one used by the OP